# Angular 5 not able to find custom pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

Everywhere I can find says that you only need to declare it in the module file what am I missing? If anyone needs more information I can add whatever is needed

Pipe file:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'partnersearch'
})
export class PartnerPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        if (value.startsWith("::ffff:")) value = value.slice(7);
        return value;
    }

}
```

module.ts file (they are in the same folder):

```
import { PartnerPipe } from './partner.pipe';

@NgModule({
imports: [],
declarations: [
    PartnerPipe
]})
```

html:

```
{{ partner | partnersearch }}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: custom pipe could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457744/angular2-custom-pipe-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular custom pipe not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45098278/1260204)

Comment: Is it in a shared module ?

Comment: possible duplicate comment. I've already tried both of those with no luck. Also the angular 2 one uses an extra file which I dont

Comment: Yes it is in a shared module

Comment: Then you should export it too.

Comment: Oh sorry do you mean is the Pipe in a share pipe file? If that is what your asking no, sorry for the confusion

Comment: So what are you expecting and what are you getting as result ?

Answer (score 3):

You should also export it if it is in a shared module.

```
import { PartnerPipe } from './partner.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PartnerPipe 
  ],
  exports: [
    PartnerPipe
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it in the module so that the components can use it.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PartnerPipe } from './partner.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PartnerPipe],
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: @amedeiros so make sure to post everything required